# Self Destructing Process Unix C

Tags: c, unix

I want to delete an executable after I start the process.

I tried by putting `unlink` and it work fine, but I want my executable to continue running.

Is using the `unlink` approach correct?  Are there any issues with using this approach?

Comment: Are you asking for help writing malware?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Unix, there shouldn't be any problems unlinking the executable of a running process.

When you unlink a file, the directory entry is removed, but the inode and the underlying data are not freed until all existing references to the file (i.e. hard links and open handles) are released.